# How to revert the selection of primeng SelectButton?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to revert the selection of primeng p-SelectButton, on user choice. I have a child component in which i have used the p-SelectButton. And the parent component renders the child component. On selection of a new value in selectbutton, a confirmation box is shown if user wants to continue. If the user chooses to cancel, the selection should go back to previous value.
I am able achieve this using 2-way binding of the model between parent and child component. On user selecting cancel, I am changing the model value back to the previous value.
But, the css class "ui-state-focus" is still added to the new selection and it looks in-focus. the previous value is shown as selected, but the new value is shown as in focus
I tried removing this class in click event, and it gets removed and when i continue the debug, it somehow gets added back. Is there a way to remove this class? after all the events are triggered? Or a simple way to achieve this (undo of the selection).

[image]

In the image the new selected value "House" still shows in focus.

```
*onclickEventParent(event) {    
    if (this.revertSelection) {
      **this.selectedFlatTypeParent = this.previousselectedFlatTypeValParent;**
      this.revertValueinClickMethodParent = false;
    } else {
      this.previousselectedFlatTypeValParent = this.selectedFlatTypeParent;
      this.currentValselectedFlatTypeParent = this.selectedFlatTypeParent;
    }
  }*
```

The issue that I am trying to solve is that once the value is reverted back, the new value still show in focus. The "ui-state-focus" class is still added to the new value element. In the image you can see "House" still highlighted. I have tried removing this - "ui-state-focus" in the component. But in the end it still gets added. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 1-way binding and assign new value or previous value on `onModelChange` event.

```
<p-selectButton [options]="types" [ngModel]="selectedFlatTypeParent" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></p-selectButton>
```

and event handler with `setTimeout` trick

```
  onChange(value: any) {
    // I use simple confirm, you can replace with your confirm way
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
      this.selectedFlatTypeParent = value;
    } else {
      let previous = this.selectedFlatTypeParent;
      this.selectedFlatTypeParent = null;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.selectedType = previous;
      });
    }
  }
```

Here is [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-moikby)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
But the actual issue that I am trying to solve is that once the value is reverted back, the new value still show in focus. The "ui-state-focus" class is still added to the new value element. In the demo you can see blue border still attached to the new value. 
I have tried removing this - "ui-state-focus" in the component. But in the end it still gets added.

Thanks in advance!!